# Using Python 3, Is there a quicker way to pick out particular cell values in an excel spreadsheet besides sorting through lists generated by xlrd?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, finance, xlrd

```
def data_search(security, statistic):
    """takes in specific asset and desired statistic (e.g. 'Gross ER', 'Asset Class', etc),
    returns the answer from the CME or Equity Ranking Template spreadsheet"""
    securities = xlrd.open_workbook('Desktop\\CME.xlsx').sheet_by_index(1)
    securities_array = securities.col_values(1, start_rowx = 1, end_rowx = securities.nrows)
    desired_security_row = securities_array.index(security) + 1
    statistics_array = securities.row_values(0, start_colx = 0, end_colx = securities.ncols)
    statistic_index = statistics_array.index(statistic)
    return securities.row(desired_security_row)[statistic_index].value
```

I'm using python's xlrd to read an excel spreadsheet to gather information and form a list of financial data for different assets. The "CME" spreadsheet referenced in the code above is essentially a spreadsheet that has about 500 different financial assets with their ticker/symbol (e.g. 'AAPL') running down column B on the spreadsheet. The x-axis has a bunch of headers for the desired statistic such as "Gross Expected Return" and "Yield". I want to be able to feed a particular ticker and desired statistic into the function and return the statistic for that ticker. The code currently uses xlrd to look at column B and generate a list out of all 500 securities (eg. ['AAPL', 'SCHB', 'DB', ...])then finds the index of that security which is how it identifies the right row. It then generates a list of all the statistic types on the spreadsheet (e.g. ['Gross Expected Return', 'Yield', 'Beta', ...]) and finds the index of the desired statistic. It will look at the correct row and return the value of whatever's in the cell of the correct index.

When I run a for-loop calling this function x amount of times on a list of tickers, it appears to be highly inefficient. I was curious to see if anyone had any ideas on a faster way to do this either involving or not involving xlrd.

Comment: Open the Workbook only **once** and read the Values direct using for example 'E5'.

Comment: `pandas` allows easy access of data, and can read `excel`-files

Comment: @stovfl thanks for your quick reply! the main issue with reading the cell directly is that I don't know which cell it'll be. the spreadsheet has about 500 securities down the Y-axis and about 15 different statistics running down the X-axis

Comment: You wrote _"The x-axis has a bunch of headers "_, therefore you have to **Index** the Header Row **only once** to get the corresponding Column. But without seeing Example Data it's all useless guessing. [Edit] your Question an show at least the Header and 3 Rows of Data and one expected Output.